# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such colum

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem with inserting data from file .txt to sql base. I have a Facebook scraper and it saves informations to txt files. Now I want to insert it from that file to sql base but I do not know sql and I have problem. Please help. Error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: 'INFORMACJE', 'KONTAKTOWE', 'Adres', 'Kraków,', 'Poland', 'PODSTAWOWE', 'INFORMACJE', 'Data', 'urodzenia', '16', 'września', '2001', 'Płeć', 'Kobieta'

```
import sqlite3 

connection = sqlite3.connect("Facebook6.db")
crsr = connection.cursor()

sql_command = """CREATE TABLE informacje (
ID INT,  
Kontakty_i_podstawowe_informacje CHAR(7000),  
Detale CHAR(7000), 
Rodzina_i_związki CHAR(7000),  
Życie_i_eventy CHAR(7000),  
Overview CHAR(7000),
Meiejsca_życia CHAR(7000),
Posty CHAR(7000),
Praca_i_edukacja CHAR(7000));
"""

crsr.execute(sql_command)

x = open('input.txt').read()
x1 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Contact and Basic Info.txt""", 
encoding="utf8").read().split()
x2 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Details About.txt""", 
encoding="utf8").read().split()
x3 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Family and Relationships.txt""", 
encoding="utf8").read().split()
x4 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Life Events.txt""", 
encoding="utf8").read().split()
x5 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Overview.txt""", encoding="utf8").read().split()
x6 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Places Lived.txt""", 
encoding="utf8").read().split()
x7 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Posts.txt""", errors='ignore').read().split()
x8 = open("""\Data"""+x+"""\Work and Education.txt""", 
encoding="utf8").read().split()

a = """INSERT INTO informacje VALUES("""+str(x1)+""", """+str(x2)+""", 
"""+str(x3)+""", """+str(x4)+""", """+str(x5)+""", """+str(x6)+""", 
"""+str(x7)+""", """+str(x8)+""")"""

crsr.execute(a)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Have you printed x1, x2 ... x8 to see their values? Does column count equal the number of values you're trying to insert?

Answer (score 0):

Looks what you want is to replace `ID INT` with `ID INT PRIMARY KEY`